# What's meaning of "n tensors" in TensorBoard graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm reading the TensorFlow tutorial code `mnist_deep.py` and save the graph.

The ouput of scope `fc1` should have shape `[-1, 1024]`. But it's `2 tensors` in the graph in TensorBoard.

What's meaning of "n tensors" in TensorBoard graph?

```
  # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
  # is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
  with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  # Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
  # features.
  with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should mean that the output tensor of Relu is used twice in the Droupout node. If you try expanding it you should see the input go into two different nodes.

Comment: I think showing `n tensors` on the graph as the number of times the tensor is "consumed" is a little confusing. In the graph above, `relu` operator only produces 1 tensor and no more. I wish Tensorboard developers consider changing this.